# How do I make the menu tabs the same width and center align the contents in them?

Tags: css

Here is the css code for the page:

```
 #drop-nav {
 width: 1000px;
 position: absolute;
 }
 #contentwrap {
 margin-top: 40px;
 }
 ul li ul li a {
 padding: 10px 18px 5px 0px;
 text-align: left;
 width: 100%;
 display: table-cell;
 }
 ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
 list-style-image: none;
 list-style-position: outside;
 overflow: visible;
 position: static;
 }
 ul li {
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 background-color: white;
 }
 li ul {
 display: none;
 background-color: #3333ff;
 }
 ul li a {
 padding: 10px 18px 5px 90px;
 background: #3333ff none repeat scroll 0% 50%;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: #ffffff;
 overflow: visible;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 }
 ul li a:hover {
 background: #3366ff none repeat scroll 0% 50%;
 overflow: visible;
 }
 li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 overflow: visible;
 }
 li:hover li {
 float: none;
 background-color: #3366ff;
 }
 li:hover a {
 background: #2346b1 none repeat scroll 0% 50%;
 }
 li:hover li a:hover {
 background: #40a3f6 none repeat scroll 0% 50%;
 }
 #drop-nav li ul li {
 border-top: 0px none;
 overflow: visible;
 visibility: visible;
 font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 text-align: justify;
 clear: none;
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 }
 #content {
 border-left: 1px solid gray;
 border-right: 1px hidden gray;
 padding: 1em;
 background-color: #dff4ff;
 float: left;
 width: 616px;
 }
 #rightcolumn {
 border: 9px hidden #dff4ff;
 margin: 0 0 -1pt;
 padding: 1em 1em 47px;
 float: right;
 clear: right;
 visibility: visible;
 width: 160px;
 background-color: #ffffcc;
 max-width: 600px;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-size: 8pt;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-family: Arial;
 }
 #container {
 border: 4px solid gray;
 margin: 10px auto;
 color: #333333;
 line-height: 130%;
 max-width: 900px;
 background-color: #dff4ff;
 overflow: hidden;
 }
 #footer {
 clear: both;
 background-color: #dff4ff;
 height: 56px;
 }
```

Here is the html code for the page:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="headerwrap">
<div id="header">
<center><img style="width: 456px; height: 142px;"
src="wkrp_c.gif" alt="logo"></center>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; <big
style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><big>&nbsp;&nbsp;
Wisnia-Kapp Reading Programs</big></big></p>
<center></center>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.jwisnia.com/wpcms/"><img
style="border: 0px solid ; width: 32px; height: 32px;" alt=""
src="arrow-88-32.png" align="middle"></a><a
target="_blank" style="font-style: italic;"
href="http://www.jwisnia.com/wpcms/">Visit Judith
Wisnia &amp; Assoc.</a><br>
<br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<ul id="drop-nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="students.html">Students</a></li>
  <li><a href="programs.html">Programs</a></li>
  <li><a href="trainings.html">Trainings</a></li>
</ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="services.html">Services Offered</a>
 </li>
 <li><a href="products.html">Our Products</a></li>
 <li><a target="_blank"
 href="http://www.jwisnia.com/wpcms/contact-us-2/">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="contentwrap">
<div id="content">
<p style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><b><span
style="text-decoration: underline;">Overview</span></b></p>
<p style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><b>WKRP</b>&nbsp;is
a rule-governed, multisensory program that involves
phonological awareness training using storytelling and
imagery. <b style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">The
WKRP Programs</b><span
style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"> were
developed by</span><b
style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"> </b>Sharon
Kapp,<b style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
</b><span style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">a&nbsp;Speech
Language Pathologist.</span>&nbsp;</p>
<p style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><b>Judith
Wisnia and Associates ("JWA")</b>&nbsp;
is a private group
practice in Speech/Language therapy, Occupational therapy, Physical
therapy, and tutoring/executive function services. JWA&nbsp;has
been
helping children since 1980. <b>JWA</b> provides <b>WKRP</b>
staff
training
and certification programs as well as contracted direct services in
school
systems in Massachusetts. Our staff has provided direct
services
to over 3,000 children. Countless other children have received <b>WKRP</b>
instruction from school teachers and individual practitioners and
tutors.&nbsp;</p>
<span style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"></span>&nbsp;<span
style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"></span><br
style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
<span style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span><span
style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><img
style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" alt=""
src="confetti-th.png" align="top"></span><span
style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span><b
style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">WKRP</b><span
style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"> is
celebrating its 24th year of providing multisensory rule-governed
phonics</span><span
style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"></span><span
style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"> materials
and
teacher instruction.
&nbsp;</span><span
 style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"></span><span
 style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"></span><span
 style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"> </span></div>
 </div>
 <div style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"
 id="rightcolumnwrap"><big>
 </big>
 <div id="rightcolumn">
 <p><big><span style="font-weight: bold;">Contact
 Us:</span><br>
 </big></p>
 <p><big><span
 style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">Judith
 Wisnia and Associates, Inc.</span><br
 style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
 <span style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">111
 South Bedford St</span><br
 style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
 <span style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">Suite
 102</span><br style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
 <span style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">Burlington,
 MA 01803</span><br>
 <br>
 &nbsp; <img style="width: 24px; height: 24px;" alt="call"
 src="phone-51-32.png" align="middle">781.272.2100<br>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;<a
 href="mailto:jwisnia@conversent.net,judithwkrp@aol.com"><img
 style="border: 0px solid ; width: 24px; height: 24px;"
 alt="email" src="email-12-32.png" align="middle"></a><a
 href="mailto:jwisnia@conversent.net,judithwkrp@aol.com">Email
 Us</a><br>
 &nbsp;<a
 href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Judith-Wisnia-><img      
style="border: 0px solid ; width: 32px; height: 32px;"
alt="Facebook" src="facebook-3-32.png"></a>
<big></p>
</div>
<div id="footerwrap">
<div id="footer">
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; Copyright © 2014 Judith Wisnia and
Associates, Inc. &nbsp;<a
href="http://home.comcast.net/%7Ejwisnia18/"><img
style="border: 2px solid ; width: 34px; height: 19px;"
alt="mainlogo"
src="http://home.comcast.net/%7Ejwisnia18/wkrp/jwalogo.gif"
align="middle"></a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The current menu items are to the right and the tab widths are uneven. They need to be aligned and equal widths. Also the submenu items should be center aligned and equal width.

Comment: A JsFiddle would help visualizing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xdnkzj7/3/). These are some new styles which I added:

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

ul li a {
    width: 175px;
    padding: 15px 0px;
}

ul li ul li a {
    padding: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

li:hover ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 174px;
}
```

Comment: The only thing is the text moves when I put my mouse over the submenus.